# How are parameters of various types accessed in Cordova iOS plugins written in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cordova-plugins

The available documentation for cordova plugins in iOS is pretty poor, and assumes knowledge of Objective C (which I have never learned).  It also seems to skip over certain things you're likely to need to know, like what a `CDVInvokedUrlCommand` is, exactly, and what types of values can be extracted from it.

I see from the header file for the type that it contains a method `argumentAtIndex:`, which I presume from [Swift examples that I've seen](https://moduscreate.com/blog/writing-a-cordova-plugin-in-swift-3-for-ios/) interacts with the swift subscript operator, as these suggest `command.arguments[number]` as a means of getting the argument.  However, I've seen no examples at any point that retrieve an argument of any type other than strings (which return either `String` or `NSString` ... and to be honest, I'm not really sure what the difference between these types is).  So as I understand it, if I get string values, I can extract them like this:

```
@objc(myStringAction:)
func myStringAction (command: CDVInvokedUrlCommand) {
    let firstString = command.arguments[0] as String;
    let secondString = command.arguments[1] as String;
    ...
}
```

So, assuming I'm implementing another action `myComplexAction` which receives: an integer, a floating point number, an array of integers, and an object containing string values.  How can I extract these into appropriate variables, and what are the resulting types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, a little bit of learning to read Objective C, and a whole load of digging in the badly-documented Cordova iOS platform library source code, it turns out that the `arguments` array in the `CDVInvokedUrlCommand` class is simply a standard array that is initialized from a JSON string using the standard platform [`NSJSONSerialization` service](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization).  Therefore, you can assume that the array contains entries of one of the following types:

- `NSString`, `NSNumber`, or `NSNull` for standard basic types.
- Note that `NSNumber` is used to encode boolean values as well as numeric ones
- `NSArray` with the same kind of entry types for any arrays
- `NSDictionary` with `NSString` keys and the same kind of entry types for object values.

Referencing from Swift, the following conversions to standard Swift value types are handled by the runtime:

- `NSString` can be converted to `String` using `as` (or implicitly for Swift 2 or earlier)
- `NSNumber` can be converted to an optional of any Swift numeric type using the `as?` operator (the conversion will fail if the contained number isn't representable in the target type).
- `NSNull` doesn't get converted, but can be tested for using `is`
- `NSDictionary` is implicitly convertible to `[AnyHashable:Any]`
- `NSArray` is implicitly converted to `[Any]`.